# How could I best structure these similar models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord, database-design

I have n models that represent orders, e.g. `EbayOrder` and `AmazonOrder`. Each order model has slightly different fields but they all represent the same basic thing, an order.

The problem is that I frequently need to query all my orders to display them in views, add up fees and sales totals, and perform other analyses on them. It's tricky to do this when the models are separate entities.

Here are some options I've considered:

**STI**

The STI table would likely be dozens of columns wide.

**Keeping separate models but generating a replica `Order` model with normalized data**

This would be a slave 'generic' model that would be a one-to-one duplicate of each type of order, but have more normalized cleaner data. I don't like this option because of the data duplication required.

**Normalize all order types into a single `Order` model**

Would be ideal if the data were similar enough, but they're pretty different among order types.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use [Polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations):

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :specific, polymorphic: true, dependent: :destroy
end

class EbayOrder < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :order, as: :specific
end

class AmazonOrder < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :order, as: :specific
end
```

In `Order` model you can keep shared attributes, but for custom attributes you can use separate model. Anyway this approach makes querying a database more complex.

Also if you use Postgres then you can review another approach: keep all orders in one table but create JSON column for custom attributes.